# get embedded image from gmail with imap php

Tags: php, image, gmail, imap

I have managed to display my emails using IMAP php library , without using any extra framework. the only problem I got is that I can not get embedded images. I can see the structure of my email with imap_fetchstrucure , that my image is somewhere in

`[1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => 5
                    [encoding] => 3
                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                    [subtype] => JPEG
                    [ifdescription] => 0
                    [ifid] => 1
                    [id] => <image002.jpg@01CE9203.CFB44C60>
                    [bytes] => 2668
                    [ifdisposition] => 0
                    [ifdparameters] => 0
                    [ifparameters] => 1
                    [parameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => name
                                    [value] => image002.jpg
                                )  )`

image002.jpg@01CE9203.CFB44C60, how can I get/show this image from Gmail? is there any standart URL to get the image www.gmail.com/image002.jpg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching  and researching , found the solution , I will not get in detail how to read the body, But in this example I have in the 4th email and 3rd part a .jpg image embedded :

```
    <?php
    $mbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) 
            or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' .       imap_last_error());
    $message=imap_fetchbody($mbox, 4,3);
    $decoded_data = base64_decode($message);
    file_put_contents('image002.jpg',$decoded_data); 
?>
    <img src="image002.jpg">  
 <?php
```

you have to save it first and then you can show it. Could not find a way to show it directly.